# Lucene storing and retrieving array in the same order

Tags: java, lucene

If I store an array in a document like this

```
for (int i=0; i<vars.length; i++ {
    Field field = new StringField("vars", vars[i], Field.Store.YES);
    doc.add(field);
}
```

when I read the document's field `vars` will I be able to get the values in the same order they were inserted?

For example for an array `['a','b','c']` is it possible to return something like `['b','c','a']` ?

Answer (score 0):

> For example for an array ['a','b','c'] is it possible to return something like ['b','c','a'] ?

It depends on your query or how you retrieve data from lucene.
AFAIK Lucene records have an internal index which is more or less an increment for each added document. This isn't a good indicator to find out which was created first, because on lucene an update of a record in actually a delete -> insert operation.

If you wanna achieve some kind of a order you should add an additional field with a timestamp or a self organized index (which i personally do not recommend).

Ordering and Sorting is a relevant thing here. You should have a look here for a simple example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lucene/lucene_sorting.htm